# Change Apache +Indexes language

Tags: htaccess, search-engine-indexing, apache2

I have a webpage with Index activated.
I have this:
[image]

Is there any way for change language of this, using `.htaccess`?

I've already tried this `Directives`:

```
AddLanguage pt .pt
DefaultLanguage pt-PT
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^.*(pt).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=lang:%1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foud a way using **jQuery** `.replace`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body table tbody tr th a').each(function(i){ // THE OBJECT WHERE IS THE REPLACEING TEXT
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Name','LOREN IPSUN'));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Last modified','LOREN IPSUN'));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Size','LOREN IPSUN'));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Description','LOREN IPSUN'));
   });
});
```

Just change *loren ipsun* for whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

As you already guessed you can use jQuery to change the styling and other things like labels. However there is a better way and that is changing Apache's index template files. This can be  done easily in the .htaccess file by using `HeaderName` and `ReadmeName` see below.

To use your own header and footer files you can use:

```
IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble
HeaderName /includes/header.html
ReadmeName /includes/footer.html
```

You could also opt to use a Directory Listing template that has been made by other people that will save you time:

1. [H5ai](http://larsjung.de/h5ai/)
2. [Apaxy](http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/)
3. [Indices](http://antisleep.com/indices-demo/)
4. [Mabishu Apache Autoindex](https://github.com/frandieguez/mabishu-apache-autoindex)
5. [Repos Style](http://www.reposstyle.com/)

Alternatively you could check out this quality guide on [making your own Directory Listing template](http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/) in several easy steps.

Comment: I dunno how this could helps. You mentioned the **way to declare header and footer**, but this will not change language values of Apache's tabs (Name, Size, Description, Last Modified) :)

Comment: The header and footer was a mere example to get you started. There is actually a few ways you can edit the values, through making your own index.php file (the content that is in the middle of the header and footer) as well as a xsl method that the ResposStyle uses. Take a look at Respos your see that the labels are there own, but all examples can be altered to meet your needs.